# Convergence rate law of iterated logarithm for a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, probability-limit-theorems, rate-of-convergence

The law of iterated logarithm has the following implication for a standard Brownian motion $(W_t, t\geq 0)$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{t\downarrow 0}\frac{W_t}{\sqrt{2t\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)}} = 1\right) = 1.
$$
I wonder if there are results shedding light on the convergence rate of the above $\limsup$. To be more specific, what can I say about the following probability,
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(W_t \leq \sqrt{2t\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)} + \varepsilon
\right),
$$
for a given $t$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$?

Comment: Very nice question I found this but this related paper but it is not exactly the results you are looking for : https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610520.pdf